# Confusion about horizonally projected body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

***DESCRIBED IN IMAGE CLEARLY***

In the text book, I got the initial velocity of *x-component initial velocity* **Vxi**, **Vxi = Vi cos(0);**  (0 = zero)

but what if it is like the picture i showed, first it was thrown from point **A** from a hill of height **h**, in angel of **beta** (suppose), then as well as it accrosed range **AB**, and at the point **B**, it has an **final velocity**, and for the second part of *motion of horizonally projected body* it is used as **initial velocity** of the body **Vi** and *angel with X axis* is **a** (alpha)

My question is,

1. in 2nd part, the x-component of velocity Vi will be **Vi cos(0)** or **Vi cos(a)** ?
   [image: defined]

Comment: The figure legend "horizontally projected **boy**" makes it a whole lot interesting (I mean it was fun imagining) :)

Answer (score 1):

In the first picture, the initial velocity in x would be $v_i\cos(a)$, and in the second picture, the initial velocity in x would be $v_j\cos(0)$

If you want to use the "textbook theory" (second picture), you cannot assume the red line in the second picture is the same as the red line in the first picture. It is, however, equivalent to the peak of the curve AB, if you manage to find the initial velocity. The $v_j$ in this case is, in an idealized case (no air resistance), the same as the horizontal component of your initial velocity at A.